# RayCastHit2D returning value only once, then stops

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics

I am trying to do a check to make sure the player is not on a wall, so that he doesn't not continue jumping upwards when hitting it, as it returns him as being grounded. I am using a RayCast2D coming out of the right side of the character to check if he is colliding with tiles tagged as ground, and if so a bool is marked true, which prevents jumping in another method. I am using a method I created to hold the RayCast and if statement, then calling it in Update so that it calls every frame. The problem is that once the wall check returns once, it never switches back to false.

I am still a relatively new noob to all of this, but I don't understand what exactly I am missing. If I have it in a separate method, then call that method every update, it should be returning these values on a frame by frame basis, right? Code below.

```
void WallCheck()
{
    LayerMask wallCheckMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Interactable");

    RaycastHit2D wallCheck = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right, wallCheckLength, wallCheckMask);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.right * wallCheckLength, Color.green);


    if (wallCheck.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {

        isOnWall = true;
        
    } else {
        isOnWall = false;
    }

    
}
```

Comment: this method is not returning anything, it is a `void`

Comment: Yeah, my wording on that was not good.. I meant the raycast is returning the hit, but only once. So I run into wall, isOnWall = true, I leave the wall, but it never flips to false, even though it is being called every frame, since I put the WallCheck method inside of Update. Just not sure what I am missing to make it not want to work.

Comment: Or other places in your code are manipulating directly the isOnWall state of your bool. If `WallCheck` is only responsible of checking if the player is in the wall, it should return that and not mask the setting of the bool inside and not return anything. That means in your Update you will have a line like `isOnWall = WallCheck()` and not just `WallCheck()`

Comment: I don't know your jump script, I just want to exclude possible errors that the jump script might set it to false as well with the logic: We jumped, so we can't be on the wall. The only thing that should change `isOnWall` should be your `WallCheck()`. So instead of a void it would be boolean and you can replace the if with `return wallCheck.collider.CompareTag("Ground")`

Comment: Awesome I will give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: Alright, so it works, but it works backwards now. So basically it says false when I'm on a wall, true when I'm on the actual ground. Good enough for me. Gonna flip the jump condition to reflect that, and it is all golden from there. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136405/discussion-between-zibelas-and-tbg).